# Deceptive site ahead google chrome when i tried to open the ngrok url

Tags: django, ngrok

recently I came across this issue when I exposed my port via ngRok.
I simply forwarded it but when I tried to open the ngRok url I got Deceptive site ahead warning.
[Here is the image of the warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xN2Jd.png).

It was a django server with graphql and I wanted to test graphiql. (this point might not be necessary for the reader but more info is always better than no info)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the solution I found was to click on the red empty area and type "thisisunsafe" (without quotes of-course)

PS: I searched for the solution but couldn't find any I hope this will help others who are looking for the same.

Answer (score 2):

Another workaround that I found is using that same URL in an incognito window. I'm not sure why the security is more lax there...but it works.